# Is there a better approach than isset and ternary for PHP 7.4? (array value and string value check)

Tags: php, php-7.4

```
$applicantName = (isset($params['applicant']['name']) && $params['applicant']['name'] != '') ? $params['applicant']['name'] : 

((isset($simulationCustomer['fullname']) && $simulationCustomer['fullname'] != '') ? $simulationCustomer['fullname'] :  

($simulationCustomer['name'] ?? ''));
```

I was this code today and of course it doesn't feel right. In JavaScript it would be so much easier to write, the problem in PHP is that the coalesce operator works for null values only.

Is there a way to write this in a more understandable way?

Comment: Even in PHP 5 you could use `!empty()` to combine `isset()` and `!= ''`

Comment: The new null coalescing operator would work for null values, but not for `""`

Comment: I guess  `($simulationCustomer['fullname']??'')?:($simulationCustomer['name'] ?? '')` kind of shortens the last bit of the first ternary. The base case could benefit from a nullsafe operator for arrays which PHP does not have (yet) so currently in PHP 8 it's shorter to work with objects and do `($params?->applicant?->name??($simulationCustomer['fullname']??'')?:($simulationCustomer['name'] ?? '')`. The magic here is `a?:b` is the same as `a?a:b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to use `array_filter`?

```
$applicantName = array_values(array_filter([
    $params['applicant']['name'] ?? '',
    $simulationCustomer['fullname'] ?? ''
]))[0] ?? '';
```

`array_values` is only for reseting index key.

Or

```
$names = array_filter([
    $params['applicant']['name'] ?? '',
    $simulationCustomer['fullname'] ?? ''
]);

$applicantName = reset($names) ?: '';
```

Comment: You would need to toss in `$simulationCustomer['name'] ?? ''` array_filter values as well, since it acts as the default value for the ternary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to check if the variables were set you could use the `??` null coalescing operator. But if you want to treat `''` as unset, you need to use `!empty()`, and this precludes using any of the conditional shorthands. the best you can do is combine the `isset()` and `!= ''` tests into `!empty()`

```
$applicantName = !empty($params['applicant']['name']) ? $params['applicant']['name'] :
                    (!empty($simulationCustomer['fullname']) ? $simulationCustomer['fullname'] : 
                        ($simulationCustomer['name'] ?? ''));
```